# add different attributes to wordpress menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

i'd like to add a custom attribute with different names for each menu item.
i just started experimenting on wordpress, so i don't know how to edit every single menu li tag.

at the moment the menu looks like this:

```
<ul id="menu-new-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13"><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-14"><a href="#tabs">tabs</a></li>
</ul>
```

what i'd like to add to it is:

```
data-menuanchor="Name_of_the_page" (different for each menu item)
```

plus this class ONLY for the first menu item:

```
class="active"
```

so it should look like this:

```
<ul id="menu-new-menu" class="menu">
    <li data-menuanchor="page-1" class="active" ... ><a href="#page-1">page-1</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="page-2" ... ><a href="#page-2">page-2</a></li>
</ul>
```

i'm doing this because i'm using a one page scroll plugin that has anchors for every section, so giving that data-menuanchor you can navigate to a specific section and give a class of "active" for both the menu items and section.

Comment: What is relationship between the href's shown in expected results and href shown in current menu? Have you tried updating child theme or are you wanting to do this with javascript? How is scroll plugin initialized?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103345/wp-nav-menu-add-attributes-to-menu-items

Comment: this is the plugin inizialization:

     $('#fullpage').fullpage({
      css3: false,
      anchors: ['contact', 'tabs', 'featured', 'grid', 'carousel', 'text'],
      menu: '.menu-new-menu-container',
      scrollingSpeed: 1000,
       });

the hrefs in the expected results are just examples... doesn't really matter if you give #page-1 or contact for what i want to achive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this get_nav_menu_locations()

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items#Examples